# How can I show that $\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1 \}$ is connected?

Tags: general-topology

I am having a lot of trouble showing that this set is connected.
$$\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 : x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1 \}$$

This set contains all of the points on the boundary of a sphere (or the surface, if you like) with a empty core/inside.

What I have tried doing is proving path connectedness, by picking two arbitrary points a and b and defining a map $ [0, 1] $ that maps on S, but I am not sure how to construct such a path since I need to go around the circle. Though a technique I have also tried is going through the sphere and simply projecting every vector on the line onto the sphere (by dividing every point on the line with its norm resulting in a unit vector) - however I am not looking for "tricks" and a rather more robust solution - something that I can learn from. :)

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This is a good line of thinking, but is tricky due to the actual difficulty of finding the explicit path, as you've discovered.

I don't know if you'd consider the following a "trick", but one approach would be to show that the sphere is the continuous image of some other connected set, for example a cube inscribed within the sphere.  It is a lot easier to show path connectedness (and thus connectedness) explicitly with a cube.  The continuous map would be the same map you suggested for trying to project the line onto the sphere, namely $\displaystyle (x, y, z) \mapsto \left( \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2, + z^2}}, \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}}, \frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}} \right)$.

---

To go "the hard way" and find an explicit path on the sphere itself between two points, you can start by convincing yourself of the following: every unit circle centered at the origin in $\mathbb{R}^3$ can be parametrized by $\cos(t) \mathbf{v}_1 + \sin(t) \mathbf{v}_2$, where $\mathbf{v}_1$ and $\mathbf{v}_2$ are orthonormal vectors in the plane of the circle.  You can set $\mathbf{v}_1$ as the first point, and then do some cross product trickery to find $\mathbf{v}_2$.

Comment: Could you explain to me how your equation works? thanks for the tip! :)

Comment: Maybe it's even easier to show that the complex plane is path connected? Then the standard projection of the plane onto the Riemann sphere minus its "North Pole" shows that the sphere with one point deleted is connected, from which it easily follows that the whole sphere is connected.

Comment: You explained it yourself above: you're just taking all the points on the cube and dividing by the norm, resulting in a unit vector @MH1993.

Comment: So the overall idea is that if I take a set S as being (path) connected and I define a continuos function that maps s onto another set then by definition f(S) is path connected.

In other words, I take a cube (which is a set in its own right) then I map those points onto the sphere? Could you explain that a little more please?

Comment: Almost @MH1993.  My suggestion was to start with a cube (which is (path)connected) and demonstrating a continuous, surjective map $\text{cube} \rightarrow \text{sphere}$.  bof is suggesting essentially the same approach, but starting with the plane and mapping it surjectively and continuously to a sphere (minus one point).

Comment: The idea being it's a lot easier to show path connectedness on the cube or on the plane, and that path connectedness (and connectedness in general) is preserved under continuous maps.

Comment: Right! I am still not sure if I fully see how this map takes every point on the cube and maps them to a sphere (without anything on the inside). Perhaps I am overcomplicating the thinking of this... What would I define the cube to be?

Comment: When you scale vectors (by dividing them by their norm, e.g.), they still point in the same direction.  Notice that if you draw a vector from the origin to every point on a cube whose center is at the origin, you have vectors pointing in *every* direction.  Therefore, when you divide each of these vectors by its norm, you now have a collection of unit vectors, one for every possible direction.

Comment: Why do these (geometrically) form a sphere? :(

Comment: If you wanted to define the cube explicitly, you'd need to do it piecewise.  Notice that each face of the cube is a plane with one variable held constant and the other two variables constrained (by the coordinates corresponding to where the corners of the cube touch the sphere).

Comment: I think I get it... I'm almost tempted to go the hard route! Though I'm definitely a fan of this preservation under continuous images theorem, I think my Linear Algebra skills are rather weak...

Comment: Try meditating on these ideas for a little while @MH1993.  If it helps, this is the map I'm trying to describe: https://blogs.scientificamerican.com/observations/files/2012/10/3d-puzzle-3.jpg

Comment: Silly question but what is the formula for a cube in R^3 anyway?

Comment: There isn't one @MH1993.  You'd have to write an equation for $6$ different planes (subject to appropriate constraints so that they're *squares* instead of the whole plane).